# tensorflow.keras can't import Activation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, importerror, keras-layer

just installed tensorflow-gpu via:

`conda install --yes tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0`

Now when I run `from tensorflow.keras import layers` into the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Activation'

I tried removing tf and keras then reinstalling tf, but hasn't helped.

Comment: Did you try ```tensorflow.python.keras```?

Comment: try:`import tensorflow as tf` then `tf.keras.layers.Activation`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a change in 1.12.0

As seen below; in 1.11, tensorflow uses tensorflow.python.keras.activations
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py

However in 1.12, it doesn't exist anymore;
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py

So, I think you can directly call the activation function as;
`keras.layers.{activation_function}`
e.g. `keras.layers.LeakyReLU`

Alternatively, you can downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

As @Amir replied, use `tensorflow.python.keras`. That worked for me!